# Вывод данных MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Дополнения к вопросу
Сейчас имею данный код:

```
   <?php
    connect();
    $sql_works = "SELECT  w.*, o.id_otdel, o.name_otdel, e.name_exam FROM works w 
    LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type 
    LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_works);
    echo '<ul id="list">';
    $i = 0;
    $name_work = Null;
    $name_otdel = Null;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($name_work != $row['name_work']) {
            if ($name_work != Null) echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
            echo '<li><p class="work_title">'.$row['name_work'].'</p>';
            echo "<ul>";    
            $name_otdel = Null;
        }
        $name_work = $row['name_work'];

        if ($name_otdel != $row['name_otdel']) {
            if ($name_otdel != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
            echo '<li><p class="otdel">'.$row['name_otdel'].'</p>';
            echo "<ul>";    
        }
        $name_otdel= $row['name_otdel'];

        echo '<li><p class="bg_li">'.$row['name_exam'].'</p></li>';
        $i++;        
    }
    echo "</ul>";    

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Данные:

- Технические работы

  - Отдел Веб-технологий

    - Ходим по кабинету
    - Перенос сайта на другой домен

- Работы 2

- Работы 3

  - Технический отдел

    - Ходим по кабинету
    - Перенос сайта на другой домен

И получается, что если нет `name_otdel`, то тег `ul` закрывается раньше!

Comment: отделите логику от представления, а то на это больно смотреть!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
<?php
connect();
$sql_works = "SELECT  w.*, o.id_otdel, o.name_otdel, e.name_exam FROM works w 
LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type 
LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
echo '<ul>';
$i = 0;

$name_work = "";
$name_otdel = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($row)) {
        $data[$i][$key] = $val; 
    } // этот код зачем нужен не знаю

    if ($name_work != $row['name_work']) {
        if ($name_work != "") echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$row['name_work'];
        echo "<ul>";    
        $name_otdel = "";
    }
    $name_work = $row['name_work'];

    if ($name_otdel != $row['name_otdel']) {
        if ($name_otdel != "") echo '</li></ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$row['name_otdel'];
        echo "<ul>";    
    }
    $name_otdel= $row['name_otdel'];

    echo '<li>'.$row['name_exam'].'</li>';

    $i++;        
}
    echo "</ul>";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Выводит кривовато) Первая запись выводится нормально, а последующие криво)

Comment: нужно исправить закрывабшие скобкию шас постараюсь исправить

Comment: Извините, не могу понять. Какие закрывающие скобки?

Comment: исправил попробуйте `$name_otdel = "";`

Comment: Извините, а с чем может быть связано то, что если в предыдущей записи нет `otdel_name`, то все рушится?

Comment: аа вот какая ситуация. Это из за того, что я брал для нет данных пустую строку. Тогда поменяйте все `$name_otdel = "";` на `$name_otdel = NULL;`

Comment: Никак не пойму... Как правильно организовать структуру. Тег `<ul>` закрывается раньше если `$name_otdel = NULL;`

Comment: @ArtemDoom покажите ваш последний результат? и если можно покажите тестовые данные. А то не понятно что у вас там

Comment: Поправил код в вопросе. А данные те же что и в примерах списков.

Comment: @ArtemDoom вы не меняйте свой первичный код, а добавьте снизу вопроса. А то не понятно будет. 2) если значения как в примере, там нет пустых отделов. все отдели имеют значения

Comment: Создал подробный ответ.