# Проблема с разметкой при выводе данных PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Пишу скрипт:

```
<?php
connect();
$sql_works = "SELECT  w.*, o.id_otdel, o.name_otdel, e.id_exam, e.name_exam, e.performer, e.customer, e.date_start, e.date_end, e.status, c.name_ch_exam FROM works w 
LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type 
LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd
LEFT JOIN child_exam c ON c.id_exam = e.id_exam";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
echo '<ul id="list">';
$i = 0;
$name_work = NULL;
$name_otdel = NULL;
$name_exam = NULL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($name_work != $row['name_work']) {
        if ($name_work != NULL) echo '</li></ul></li></ul>';
        echo '<li><p class="work_title">'.$row['name_work'].'</p>';
        echo "<ul>";    
        $name_otdel = NULL;
    }
    $name_work = $row['name_work'];

    if ($name_otdel != $row['name_otdel']) {
        if ($name_otdel != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
        echo '<li><p class="otdel">'.$row['name_otdel'].'</p>';
        echo "<ul>";    
    }
    $name_otdel= $row['name_otdel'];

     if ($name_exam != $row['name_exam']) {
        if ($name_exam != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
    echo "<li><p class='bg_li'><textarea readonly>".$row['name_exam'] . "</textarea><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['performer'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['customer'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['date_start'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['date_end'] ."'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['status'] ."'><a class='win' href='#win_upexam_".$row['id_exam']."'><img src='img/edit.png' width='20'></a></p>";
    echo "<ul>";  
    }
     $name_exam= $row['name_exam'];

     echo '<li><p class="bg_li">'.$row['name_ch_exam'].'</p></li>';

    $i++;        
}
echo "</ul>";    

mysql_close();
?>
```

На данном этапе запутался в разметке `<ul> <li>`. Выводится все очень криво... Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А можно предложить другой подход? У Вас структура очень похожа на дерево... Как категории в онлайн-магазинах... Я бы предложил после вытаскивания данных из БД перевести в массив с подмассивами, который повторяет Ваше дерево. А уже потом с этим массивом и работать... Вывод данных с использование рекурсивных функций вообще становится простейшим делом :)

Comment: @cyadvert Пока сроки горят и получается сделать только так...

Comment: Ну хорошо... "выводится криво" - это как? Не хватает какого открывающего или закрывающего тэга?

Comment: @cyadvert Ну вот если `$name_otdel != NULL`, то тег закрывается раньше чем нужно...

Comment: Нет, все-таки без примерных данных сложно... Может какой fiddle сделаешь? Ну или хотя бы содержимое `$result`

Comment: Приведите код в божий вид и сразу станет видно, где с разметкой проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так, но очень мутно все сделали. Что то не то, так как вы уже показывали этот вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457519/182317)

```
<?php
connect();
$sql_works = "SELECT  w.*, o.id_otdel, o.name_otdel, e.id_exam, e.name_exam, e.performer, e.customer, e.date_start, e.date_end, e.status, c.name_ch_exam FROM works w 
LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type 
LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd
LEFT JOIN child_exam c ON c.id_exam = e.id_exam";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
echo '<ul id="list">';
$i = 0;
$name_work = NULL;
$name_otdel = NULL;
$name_exam = NULL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($name_work != $row['name_work']) {
        if ($name_work != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
        echo '<li><p class="work_title">'.$row['name_work'].'</p>';
        echo "<ul>";    
        $name_otdel = NULL;
    }
    $name_work = $row['name_work'];

    if ($name_otdel != $row['name_otdel']) {
        if ($name_otdel != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
        echo '<li><p class="otdel">'.$row['name_otdel'].'</p>';
        echo "<ul>";    
    }
    $name_otdel= $row['name_otdel'];

     if ($name_exam != $row['name_exam']) {
        if ($name_exam != NULL) echo '</li></ul>';
    echo "<li><p class='bg_li'><textarea readonly>".$row['name_exam'] . "</textarea><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['performer'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['customer'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['date_start'] . "'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['date_end'] ."'><input type='text' readonly value='" . $row['status'] ."'><a class='win' href='#win_upexam_".$row['id_exam']."'><img src='img/edit.png' width='20'></a></p>";
        echo "<ul>";    
    }
    $name_otdel= $row['name_exam'];




 //    echo '<li><p class="bg_li">'.$row['name_ch_exam'].'</p></li>';

    $i++;        
}
echo "</ul>";    

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Так как раз и не выходит. Записей много, а он закрывает тег дойдя до первого `name_otdel = null`