# сгруппирировать записи на вывод php

Tags: php, mysql

Структура таблицы

```
id  username    org    tel     section
1   qwerty      com    123      1
2   admin       inter  2225     1
3   vasaya      gg     4421     4
4   john        olen   2        3
5   petr        zed    332      3
```

как сгруппирировать вывод в цикле на подобный вид?

```
секция 1 
qwerty  
admin   
секция 3
john       
petr         
секция 4
vasaya
```

Comment: Реализация в ответе на этот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457593/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-php-mysql вопрос. Да и в самом вопросе подход с выводом групп тоже правильный.

Comment: а причем здесь разметка?

Comment: Вопрос в комментарии от cyadvert является вам ответом ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот SQL, который выводит, то, что Вы хотите:

```
SELECT res.str
FROM (
    SELECT IF(ISNULL(username), 0, w.section) AS isParent, w.section, IFNULL(username, CONCAT('section ', w.section))  AS str
    FROM _wTemp w
    GROUP BY w.section, w.username WITH ROLLUP) res
WHERE NOT ISNULL(res.str)
ORDER BY res.section, res.isParent ASC;
```

Если надо, могу объяснить... Однако заклинаю - не пользуйтесь им...  :)

Возьмите лучше вот этот вариант вывода через `php`:

```
$currentSection = NULL;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($currentSection!=$row["section"]) {
        echo "<div>Секция " .  $row["section"] . "</div>";
        $currentSection = $row["section"];
    }
    echo "<div>" . $row["username"] . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: при запросе SELECT * FROM table дважды выводит одну и ту же секцию

Comment: не понял... Так Вам SQL запрос нужен? тогда зачем "вывод в цикле" и метка `php`?

Comment: php, mysql, ведь откуда то данные берутся

Comment: еще раз.... у Вас есть таблица, которую Вы привели. Надо - SQL запрос, который бы выдавал одну колонку так, как Вы указали. А потом этот запрос Вы хотите с помощью `php` выводить на экран. Я правильно понял?

Comment: php сам выведу, сам бы запрос построить, с помощью DISTINCT делаю, но максимум чего я достиг так это сгруппирировать секции а вот остальные данные не могу вывести

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, не нужен там ни какой заумный запрос. Делаете только сортировку по section и id. А вывод делает скрипт, который в этом ответе.

Comment: Все-таки еще раз переспрошу: Вы уверены, что именно через SQL запрос хотите действовать? Просто судя по данным, придется делать `GROUP BY `, потом `JOIN` таблицу с самой собой... Вобщем морочно, долго... Считать таблицы и вывести в `php`, как я написал, будет намного быстрее и проще

Comment: все равно через что действовать, абы из БД выводилась структура которую я описал

Comment: я добавил SQL  в ответ

Comment: спасибо немножко подпилил и вышло как надо)

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, поставь лучше галочку. Нам на сообществе надо повышать кол-во закрытых вопросов... А-то ДухСообщества ежедневно такой бред из истории достает... Спасибо